# file extentions in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have created a file upload website where I want to allow users to upload files in pdf, ppt, doc, txt, and zip format. I am using the HTML form to upload files.

models.py:

```
class Upload_Notes(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
uploadingdate = models.CharField(max_length=30)
branch = models.CharField(max_length=30)
subject = models.CharField(max_length=50)
notesfile = models.FileField(null=True)
filetype = models.CharField(max_length=30)
description = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
status = models.CharField(max_length=15)

def __str__(self):
      return f'{self.user} notes'
```

view.py

```
def upload_notes(request):
if request.method=='POST':
    branch = request.POST['branch']
    subject = request.POST['subject']
    notes = request.FILES['notesfile']
    filetype = request.POST['filetype']
    description = request.POST['description']

    user = User.objects.filter(username=request.user.username).first()
    Upload_Notes.objects.create(user=user,uploadingdate=date.today(),branch=branch,subject=subject,notesfile=notes,
                             filetype=filetype,description=description,status='pending')
    messages.success(request,f"Notes uploaded from {request.user.username} successfully!")
    return redirect('/view_mynotes')
return render(request,'user/upload_notes.html')
```

I want to do like When the user selects file type PDF and if he trying  to upload a file with another extension then an error should be popup ***Please upload pdf file*** and it should be same for all extensions like ppt doc zip txt
please help me to achieve this

Comment: When you included the validator (from the tutorial) in your model did it seem to get ignored or did you get an error?

Comment: @ Jacinator validator seems to get ignored

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem using [this article](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/01/how-to-upload-files-with-django.html).

You can validate the file extensions to be uploaded with the following function.

```
import os
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.db import models

def validate_file_extension(value):
ext = os.path.splitext(value.name)[1]  # [0] returns path+filename
valid_extensions = ('.pdf', '.ppt', '.doc')  # Only allowed extensions.
if not ext.lower() in valid_extensions:
    raise ValidationError('Unsupported file.')


class ExampleModel(models.Model):
    example_field = models.FileField(
        'Example Field',
        upload_to='upload_folder/',
        validators=(validate_file_extension, )
    )
```

Comment: thanks to your response @Umut but this solution is not working for me, when I select filetype PDF  and instead of uploading a PDF file I upload an Excel file It uploads successfully without any error